# Entity Framework with both SQL Server and MySQL servers from a single ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

```
protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (vhkEntities entities = vhkEntities.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("mysql"))
        {
            var empl = (from emp in entities.Employees where emp.EmpId == "1" select emp);
            Employee obj = empl.Single();
            obj.EmpId = "2";
            obj.Name = "BBB";
            int n = entities.SaveChanges();
}

public static vhkEntities CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName(string databaseName, bool contextOwnsConnection = true)
{
        string sqlConnectionString = "";
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        if (databaseName == "mysql")
        {
            entityBuilder.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
            sqlConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=welcome@12;database=vhk;";
        }
        else
        {
            entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            sqlConnectionString = "data source = DS-448A5BAEB93E; user id = sa; password = welcome@12; initial catalog = vhk;";
        }
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;

        //Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = string.Format("res://{0}/EF.csdl|res://{0}/EF.ssdl|res://{0}/EF.msl",
        typeof(vhkEntities).Assembly.FullName);
        //Create entity connection
        EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
        return new vhkEntities(connection);
}
```

I am trying to use Entity Framework to connect to both SQL Server and MySQL machines from my asp.net project. I have created one `.edmx` file for SQL Server database, so I want to use the same `.edmx` file to perform crud operations on both SQL Server and MySQL databases.

For insert operation it is working fine for both servers but coming to select operation I'm getting an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "I want to use the same edmx file to perform crud operations on both SQL and MySQL servers". Don't think you can, because each edmx requires its own connection string to a specific database. I guess you could vary the string at runtime, but still it's a horrible kludge, hence why you're getting type conversion errors - I imagine EF is getting confused. Nothing stopping you having two edmx's though. Makes more sense anyway, because each DB is a separate model.

Comment: ADyson , thank u very for your comments,

Comment: At what point are you getting this Exception? I am thinking maybe you are trying to use an existing instance of the context and point it to a new database? Or is it when you instantiate a new instance? Showing the code where the Exception occurs would help shed some more light on this.

Comment: using (vhkEntities entities = vhkEntities.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("mysql"))                While creating the instance only im getting the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but I didn't do anything special with the edmx files. I actually had to create a new solution and copy over my work to it because I couldn't get the config right in my existing solution. With my new solution first I connected to my the mssql server, and made sure that worked. Then I added all the latest version mysql nuget packages (MySql.Data, Mysql.Data.Entity, MySql.Fabric, and MySql.Web). I had separate projects in my solution for the data and the UI, so I needed to copy over some stuff from my data project's app.config to the UI project's web.config.